Nyaya's defense of Ashwamedha Yajna
The Charvakas criticized the Vedic text for rituals they considered nonsensical and weird particularly Ashwamedha. Nyaya likely had some interactions with Charvakas seeing as they considered them tricky and the fact they almost never provide an alternative and only critcize. So, did a Nyayaika defend Ashwamedha if so how?
